# I can't apply the classes I get as variables while generating the react library

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a little library with create-react-library. The classes i render are not working properly.

Example Component > App.js

```
import { Button, Button2 } from 'lofiui'
import 'lofiui/dist/index.css'

const App = () => {
  return(
    <>
      <Button type="primaryButton" text="Click ME" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Library > index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.css'

export const Button = ({ type, text }) => {
  return <button className={`${styles}.${type}`}>{text}</button>
}
```

class of rendered button:

[image]

How can I use the primaryButton class I produced for buttons?

Comment: `styles` is an object, not a string, no? Wouldn't you want to refer to `${styles[type]}` or something? (Depending on how your CSS is being loaded, I guess.)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `styles` import will be an object, not a string, so string interpolation won't give the results you want. This would be apparent by inspecting the generated DOM in the browser tools.

```html
<button className={`${styles}.${type}`}>
  {text}
</button>
```

In the DOM this might look like:

```
className="[object object].some_type"
```

(Or similar.)

You want to use `type` as the `styles` key to look up, so something like:

```html
<button className={`${styles[type]}`}>
  {text}
</button>
```